# How to use variable at start of django url to return to view?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to pass the first part of a django url to a view, so I can filter my results by the term in the url.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/), it seems quite straightforward.

However, I have the following urls.py

```
url('<colcat>/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
url('<colcat>/', views.collection_view, name='collection_view'),
```

In this case, I want to be able to go to `/living` and have `living` be passed to my view so that I can use it to filter by.

When trying this however, no matter what url I put it isn't being matched, and I get an error saying the address I put in could not be matched to any urls.

What am I missing?

Comment: perhaps you are missing the trailing slash. i.e go to `/living/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<colcat>` is not a valid regex. You need to use the same format as you have for `name`.

```
url('(?P<colcat>[\w\-]+)/collection/(?P<name>[\w\-]+)$', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
url('(?P<colcat>[\w\-]+)/$', views.collection_view, name='collection_view'),
```

Alternatively, use the new `path` form which will be much simpler:

```
path('<str:colcat>/collection/<str:name>', views.collection_detail, name='collection_detail'),
path('<str:colcat>/', views.collection_view, name='collection_view'),
```